# How to add querySnapshot result together in one variable?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

> In this case doc.data().totalVarighet returns two values. I want to add those values together and put the result into one variable.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if(user){
        var userId=firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
        var curMonthAndYear=document.getElementById('monthAndYear').innerHTML;
        console.log(curMonthAndYear)
        db.collection("users").doc(userId).collection('plannedEx').where("monthAndYear", "==", curMonthAndYear)
        .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
            var exercises = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                exercises.push(doc.data().totalVarighet);
            });
            console.log("Current exercises in this month: ", exercises.join(", "));
        });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't allow multiple return values. If `doc.data().totalVarighet` is returning multiple data items they are definitely wrapped inside some kind of `Object`, which can easily be assigned to a single variable which what you want.

Comment: Yes it's wrapped inside an Object. Thanks for the answer.